# Snowflake Change Tracking to implement SCD2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, scd2

Has anyone used change tracking feature in Snowflake to track DML changes on a table and create SCD2 tables in a Snowflake data warehouse? Not talking about using streams and tasks but specifically turning on change tracking on the table and using a stored procedure/ SQL to create SCD2 tables.

Link to documentation : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes

It looks like a possible way to implement scd2 but want to know if anybody has implemented it already. Also, when the feature was introduced and if it is stable.

Comment: Hi - it was implemented months/years ago and is stable. However, I’m wondering why you’d want to use it to build an SCD2 solution when using streams would normally be a better solution? What’s your use case that makes this type of change tracking a better solution than streams?

Comment: I was wondering if using change tracking is easier than streams because you don't need to create another object.

Comment: I doubt it. Streams automatically tracks the last record that you wrote to your Dim table so you can do incremental updates of only the changes made since the last update. If you used CHANGES then you'd have to implement this sort of mechanism yourself

Comment: Can't I insert/update my dim table and then query the changed records using 'changes' clause and write to a history table that maintain versions?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense (to me). The changed records are the source for what you need to write to your Dim - which contains the history, that's what and SCD2 Dim table is, it holds history

Comment: If I have a dim table and dim_history table and maintain version history in the dim_history table and enable change tracking on the dim table, it should work right? Insert/update dim table every time from source and get the changes using metadata into the history table.

Comment: That's not an SCD2 table (which was what your question was about) and is not a standard design pattern. Anyway, this is turning into a discussion so I'm going to stop at this point. If you have another specific coding question then feel free to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your model so based on what you provided, I am assuming the following :
You need a measure that calculates the total number of unique sizes planned for each option (Style + Color) in the merial mater planned table.

```
 Total Sizes Planned = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Material Master Planned'[Size]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Material Master Planned', 'Material Master Planned'[Option])
    )
```

Then , create a measure to count the distinct sizes available in the ientory table for each option.

```
Available Sizes = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Inventory'[Size]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Inventory', 'Inventory'[Option])
)
```

Then another measure that calculates the percentage of available sizes against the total sizes planned for each option.

```
Efficiency Percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    [Available Sizes], 
    [Total Sizes Planned]
)
```

Then finally the measure for the health status :

```
  Health Status = 
    IF(
        [Efficiency Percentage] >= 0.7, 
        "Healthy", 
        "Unhealthy"
    )
```